# Flutter Apple Pay error in release mode IOS but not in debug

Tags: flutter, applepay

Hy,
I try to publish 2 app with Apple Pay system in. But i have a problem, all work with my simulator, but when im in test flight with Apple, Apple Pay dont work/ nothing is show when i call function.
I cant do payment.
I have already try with Stripe but same Issue
I already add ApplePay certificat in X-Code.
Thanks for help and have a good day

flutter doctor - v :

```
    fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (5 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Library/Android/
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Users/Desktop/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
          •
      iOS 15.3 19D5026g
    • Chrome (web)             • chrome                    • web-javascript •
      Google Chrome 97.0.4692.71
    ! Error: iPhone de Kévin is busy: Preparing the watch for development via
      iPhone de Kévin. Xcode will continue when iPhone de Kévin is finished.
      (code -10)

• No issues found! 
My Code 
void _onStartApplePay() async {
    print('Start');
    try {
      await InAppPayments.requestApplePayNonce(
          price: '$totalEnd',
          summaryLabel: 'Name',
          countryCode: 'FR',
          currencyCode: 'EUR',
          paymentType: ApplePayPaymentType.finalPayment,
          onApplePayNonceRequestSuccess: _onApplePayNonceRequestSuccess,
          onApplePayNonceRequestFailure: _onApplePayNonceRequestFailure,
          onApplePayComplete: _onApplePayEntryComplete);
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {}
  }

  void _onApplePayNonceRequestSuccess(context) async {
    try {
      // take payment with the card nonce details
      // you can take a charge
      // await chargeCard(result);

      // you must call completeApplePayAuthorization to close apple pay sheet
      await InAppPayments.completeApplePayAuthorization(isSuccess: true);
    } on Exception catch (ex) {
      // handle card nonce processing failure

      // you must call completeApplePayAuthorization to close apple pay sheet
      await InAppPayments.completeApplePayAuthorization(
          isSuccess: false, errorMessage: 'error');
    }
    paiement = true;
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/paiementTrue');
  }

  void _onApplePayNonceRequestFailure(ErrorInfo errorInfo) async {
    await InAppPayments.completeApplePayAuthorization(
        isSuccess: false, errorMessage: errorInfo.message);
    print('Request fail');
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/paiementFalse');
    print(errorInfo.message);
  }

  void _onApplePayEntryComplete() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/paiementFalse');
  }
```

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Comment: No, i use API Stripe CURL for payment but with Card and dont use ApplePay/GooglePay

Answer (score -1):

```
Error: iPhone de Kévin is busy: Preparing the watch for development via
iPhone de Kévin. Xcode will continue when iPhone de Kévin is finished.
```

[image]

You will generally see this message once per OS version. There is a bunch of prep work Xcode needs to do in order to allow running and debugging of an app, such as collecting the system symbols from the OS version to allow for debugging.

Nothing todo but wait